# Is there any difference in JComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString() and JTextField.getText()?

Tags: java, arrays, spring, performance, swing

I want send SMS to numbers stored in a `JComboBox` and but not working as makes the system to freeze. However getting Phone number from `JTextField` is working but getting it from a combo box is not
and throws this error:

```
15:12:54.672 [AWT-EventQueue-0] ERROR smslib - GTW: : CMS Error 500: 
Quit retrying, message lost...
```

[Sms Sender App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fxKp.png)

```
AbstractTester at = new AbstractTester() {
    @Override
    protected void test() throws Exception {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
    }
};

OutboundNotification outboundNotification = at.new OutboundNotification();
SerialModemGateway gateway = new SerialModemGateway("", cmbPorts.getSelectedItem().toString(), 9600, "", "");
gateway.setInbound(true);
gateway.setOutbound(true);
Service.getInstance().setOutboundMessageNotification(outboundNotification);
Service.getInstance().addGateway(gateway);
Service.getInstance().startService();

for (int i = 0; i < cmbNumbers.getItemCount(); i++) {

    OutboundMessage msg = new OutboundMessage(cmbNumbers.getItemAt(i), smsArea.getText());
    Service.getInstance().sendMessage(msg);

    txtAreaLog.append(msg.toString());
    Service.getInstance().stopService();
    Service.getInstance().removeGateway(gateway);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Message has been sent successfully to:" + cmbNumbers.getItemAt(i) + "");
}
```

Comment: You should really try to improve your question by fixing the formatting and providing a better description of your issue, if possible even a [mre].

Comment: That aside, looking at your screenshot, the "number" in your `JComboBox` seems to start with an "O" instead of a "0". That might be the problem.

Comment: Why don't you print out the strings to the console and see?

Comment: maloomeister,hahaha, thank you very much,iv bn on it for a week now.Never crossed my mind!. O vs 0 lol.

Comment: Gilbert Le Blanc , i did that but failed to see the difference between O and 0.

Comment: Tip: Add @maloomeister (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: Do not refer to external resources (image). If the remote site is down your question cannot be understood. Further try to isolate the problem. Why do we have to read through all of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Change your for loop from:

for (int i = 0; i < cmbNumbers.getItemCount(); i++)

To as mentioned below:

for (int i = 0; i <= cmbNumbers.getItemCount()-1; i++)

It seems there is some issue in your for loop declaration.